# Getting error when I add drawing feature to the map

Tags: javascript, openlayers

I use [OpenLayers 6](https://openlayers.org/).
I try to add to the map interaction a class to draw features on the map.

Here is MapDraw class:

```
function MapDraw() {

        this.vector = new ol.layer.Vector({
            source: new ol.source.Vector()
        });

        Draw.call(this, {
            source: this.vector.getSource(),
            type: "Point"
        });

        this.on = Draw.prototype.on;
        this.on('drawend', function (e) {
            eventsHandlers.featureComplete;         
        });
    }

    if (Draw) MapDraw.__proto__ = Draw;
    MapDraw.prototype = Object.create(Draw && Draw.prototype);
    MapDraw.prototype.constructor = Draw;

    $("#popupShapes").popup("close");

    return MapDraw;
}(ol.interaction.Draw));
```

Here how I add class above to the map interaction:

```
map.addInteraction(new MapDraw());
```

But when add interaction occurred on this block:

```
    Draw.call(this, {
            source: this.vector.getSource(),
            type: "Point"
        });
```

I get the following error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: r.setActive is not a function
```

Any idea why i get the error and how to fix it?

Comment: What should this `eventsHandlers.featureComplete` be? Where should it come from? What should it do?

Comment: @TomazicM thank you for the question. It is some function that fired in when feature drew on the map.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm no expert in ES6 and class extension, but in the above code several things are wrong. It's strange mixture of ES5 (`ol.layer.Vector` class) and ES6 (`Draw` class). Then there is definitely syntax error of one closing `}` misplaced or too much. But the main error is that class extension part should be outside class definition part.

Taking all this into account, class definition/extension in ES5 could look like this:

```
function MapDraw() {
  this.vector = new ol.layer.Vector({
    source: new ol.source.Vector()
  });
  ol.interaction.Draw.call(this, {
    source: this.vector.getSource(),
    type: "Point"
  });
  this.on = ol.interaction.Draw.prototype.on;
  this.on('drawend', function (e) {
    console.log('Draw ended.');         
  });
};

if (ol.interaction.Draw) MapDraw.__proto__ = ol.interaction.Draw;
MapDraw.prototype = Object.create(ol.interaction.Draw && ol.interaction.Draw.prototype);
MapDraw.prototype.constructor = ol.interaction.Draw;
```

Looking at internals of `ol-ext` plugin, class extension can be further simplified, so final version in ES5 could look something like this (tested with the latest ol6):

```
function MapDraw() {
  this.vector = new ol.layer.Vector({
    source: new ol.source.Vector()
  });
  ol.interaction.Draw.call(this, {
    source: this.vector.getSource(),
    type: "Point"
  });
  this.on = ol.interaction.Draw.prototype.on;
  this.on('drawend', function (e) {
    console.log('Draw ended.');         
  });
};

MapDraw.prototype = Object.create(ol.interaction.Draw.prototype);
MapDraw.prototype.constructor = MapDraw;
.
.
.
var mapDraw = new MapDraw();
map.addInteraction(mapDraw);

mapDraw.on('drawend', function(e) {
  console.log('I agree, draw ended.');
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the post. I need to use Draw object in the drawend event. How can I access it?

Comment: In answer above your question about error was answered. If not, please explain why not. If you have another question, please post it as separate question.